# ggplot multiple time series of unequal time

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I know there are a few answered questions relating to timeseries and multiple dataframes, but I cant seem to figure this out.

I would like to plot time stamped data of 4 different pressure senors against time (column pa). I have 4 dfs of time stamped pressure readings from the same experiment. However, the sensors collected data at unequal times and the length of the columns are unequal due to sensor failures and other blips in the data.

These two aspects have prevented me from successfully creating a graph containing all 4 sensors' data. All of the df are of unequal number of observations but within the same range, but they differ at the seconds level. Would the time resolution need to be changed to hours, for example?

This is what the df looks like: PA_1 n=1097361

```
      time               pa       wifi
1 2014-09-01 16:21:00   100.620    1   
2 2014-09-01 17:20:33   100.572    1 
3 2014-09-01 18:20:05   100.561    0
4 2014-09-01 19:19:38   100.523    0
5 2014-09-01 20:19:11   100.511    1    
6 2014-09-01 21:18:43   100.534    1

PA_2: n=914364
       time              pa        wifi
1 2014-09-01 15:25:05   NA         1 
2 2014-09-01 15:25:09   100.798    1
3 2014-09-01 15:25:11   100.792    0              
4 2014-09-01 15:25:15   100.791    0              
5 2014-09-01 15:25:18   100.790    1             
6 2014-09-01 15:25:20   100.791    1  

PA_3 n=963527
       time              pa        wifi
1 2014-09-01 15:25:02   100.832    1
2 2014-09-01 15:25:05   100.832    1
3 2014-09-01 15:25:08   100.825    0
4 2014-09-01 15:25:11   100.831    0
5 2014-09-01 15:25:14   100.830    1
6 2014-09-01 15:25:17   100.836    1   

PA_4: n = 1061117
       time              pa        wifi
1 2014-09-01 15:25:00   100.690    1
2 2014-09-01 15:25:04   100.683    1
3 2014-09-01 15:25:07   100.685    0
4 2014-09-01 15:25:11   100.687    0
5 2014-09-01 15:25:14   100.682    1
6 2014-09-01 15:25:18   100.684    1
```

Also, a dichotomous variable "wifi" was added to the df to denote when wifi was on or off during the experiment.Two of the sensors were exposed to wifi while two were outside of the wifi signal. 
I would like to display this in a graph as well. Perhaps by shading the region or increasing the size of the lines when wifi was on during the experiment, but I am not too sure how to do this. To illustrate this, I edited the middle 2 wifi entries in the examples, but wifi was on for periods of 10 days at a time, not a few seconds.

Thanks

edit: added examples of each df and added a few explinations

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to get all four as one single line?  And then perhaps split by the wifi variable?

Comment: Post samples of the other 3 sensors also

Comment: Also, are you trying to plot the 4 sensors as 4 different series, or are you combining them to form 1 series? (I think @jaysunice3401 is inferring the latter in his/her answer)

Comment: @arvi1000 I went ahead and added additional code to my answer to show possibilities of plotting the 4 sensors/datasets separately.

Comment: Yeah I had an answer similar to that last scenario, but deleted pending clarification of the question from OP. Guess I may as well let it show

Comment: Hi 4 separate lines representing each pressure sensor. Sorry for not being clear I will edit the OP now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear to me what you are asking, but (if this what you are trying to do) you can combine the data.frames then plot them all on one chart, using color to differentiate sensors, and alpha/shape settings to differentiate wifi status. Then it's no problem that the series start and end at different times, and have different measurement resolutions.

Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(x=time, y=pa, group=sensor,  
           color=factor(sensor),  alpha=factor(wifi))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(wifi)), size=3) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(.3, 1))
```

Which (using totally random data) looks like this:

[image]

To generate random data, I did this:

library(lubridate)

```
# fake data
set.seed(123)
n <- 40

dat <-
  data.frame(sensor=sample(1:4, n, replace=T),
             hr=sample(1:24, n, replace=T), 
             min=sample(1:60, n, replace=T),
             sec=sample(1:60, n, replace=T),
             wifi=rbinom(n, 1, .5),
             pa=100+rnorm(n))

dat$time <- with(dat, ymd_hms(paste('2014-09-01', 
                                    paste(hr, min, sec, sep=':'))))
```

Comment: Ah ok! I understand. I am going to add a "Sensor ID" column and rbind() the 4 dfs into one and follow your code. thanks you!

Comment: after concatenating the data into 1 df, here is the first output: http://imgur.com/PCeKTYb, and i think the current way of displaying if wifi was on/off is not that clear. Maybe on the x axis or changing the thinkness of the line.

Comment: Also, how would I get sensors 1 & 4 to show up as the same color and senors 2 & 3 as a different color?

Comment: When you add the "Sensor ID" column, just make the values '1 & 4' for both 1 & 4 and '2 & 3' for both 2 & 3 (or make it a new column called Sensor_Group or something)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you may be getting hung up with `group=1` -- you must use `aes(group=1)` so that `ggplot()` knows to connect the data together in a line.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create some data
set.seed(1)
PA_1 <- data.frame(time = Sys.Date()+rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                   pa   = 100 + rnorm(20, 0, 2),
                   wifi = sample(0:1, 20, 2),
                   dset = 1)

PA_2 <- data.frame(time = Sys.Date()+rnorm(15, 0, 1),
                   pa   = 100 + rnorm(15, 0, 2),
                   wifi = sample(0:1, 15, 2),
                   dset = 2)

PA_3 <- data.frame(time = Sys.Date()+rnorm(25, 0, 1),
                   pa   = 100 + rnorm(25, 0, 2),
                   wifi = sample(0:1, 25, 2),
                   dset = 3)

PA_4 <- data.frame(time = Sys.Date()+rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                   pa   = 100 + rnorm(20, 0, 2),
                   wifi = sample(0:1, 20, 2),
                   dset = 4)

# Combine the dataframes
df <- do.call(rbind, list(PA_1, PA_2, PA_3, PA_4))
head(df)
#         time        pa wifi dset
# 1 2015-01-11 101.83795    0    1
# 2 2015-01-12 101.56427    1    1
# 3 2015-01-11 100.14913    0    1
# 4 2015-01-13  96.02130    0    1
# 5 2015-01-12 101.23965    1    1
# 6 2015-01-11  99.88774    0    1


# Variation 1
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pa, group=1)) +
  geom_line()

# Variation 2
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pa, group=wifi, color=factor(wifi))) +
  geom_line()

# Variation 3
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pa, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~wifi)

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=1)
```

[image: Results]

Alternatively, if you choose to keep the datasets "separate" you could do one of the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pa, group=dset, color=factor(dset))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Separate01]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pa, color=factor(dset))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(wifi~dset)
```

[image: Separate02]